# iOS reachability for socket connection

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets, reachability

I need to check for reachability for a socket connection in my application. I have gone through apple's sample code and few examples I could find from SO and other websites but I'm out of luck as I do not get any response. Here's a sample code I'm trying.

My requirement is simply to verify connectivity to myhost:port which is a socket connection. myhost is an address from dyndns.org

```
struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    server_address.sin_len = sizeof(server_address);
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(1234);
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("host-from-dyndns.org");

    Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithAddress:&server_address];

    __weak Reachability *weakReachability = reachability;
    reachability.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"REACHABLE!");
        });
        [weakReachability stopNotifier];
    };

    reachability.unreachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
    {
        NSLog(@"UNREACHABLE!");
        [weakReachability stopNotifier];
    };

    [reachability startNotifier];
```

Comment: link which you are using for reachability is secured server? ex : starts with http:// or https:// ?

Comment: no its non secured server. nothing special about it other than the ip address is not static, hence current ip is resolved through dyndns.org.

Comment: first check with  Reachability* reachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];

Comment: with this you will know that does your reachability is implemented properly or not

Comment: thanks, yes i've tried it for a generic example like that and it works fine. only when i provide my server & port. it fails to give any response.

Comment: is your link contains subdirectories I mean http://yourdomainname.com/subdomain/etc.etc then try using only yourdomainname.com and please check once that your port number is correct or not

Comment: no there are no sub directories. it's just host:port. the server & client is functioning properly. the task i'm working on right now is to add in a reachability check for the connection so I can know when there is difficulty with connectivity and inform the user. the socket client i have implemented using cfstreams.

Comment: `startNotifier` returns BOOL, positive value if the service is scheduled or negative otherwise. What is your result ?

Comment: `BOOL status = [reachability startNotifier];`

status is true/YES after executing code

Comment: check once with port number - 8080, this might works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few failed attempts of meddling with with reachability classes, I gave up and used a temporary asynchronous socket connection created on demand to verify the connection. It works as expected and is built on top of gcd. Also I found the AsyncSocket by Robbie Hanson (https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) to be quite helpful while implementing for my requirement.